# Interpretation for Quran 69:46

Tags: quran, tafseer

> Then We would have cut from him the aorta
>
> [Quran 69:46](https://quran.com/69/44-52?translations=20)

What is the interpretation for this verse?

Comment: Random downvoter, at least give me feedback or tell me what I should improve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole passage is

It is the speech of a noble messenger. (40) And it is not the speech of a poet—little do you believe. (41) Nor is it the speech of a soothsayer—little do you take heed. (42) It is a revelation from the Lord of the Worlds. (43) Had he falsely attributed some statements to Us. (44) We would have seized him by the right arm. (45) Then slashed his lifeline. And none of you could have restrained Us from him.(47)

It says that Muhammad (p.b.u.h) did not invent the Qur'an.

It doesn't say that God would do that to whoever would do alike during his life on Earth. This can be drawn from mere observation.